# Finding the eigenvectors using a calculator?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, calculator

Can I find the eigenvectors using a regular calculator or a graphical calculator?

```
[0.6881-(1.3978)   -0.5929] [x1] = [-0.7097 -0.5929]

[-0.5929   (0.9026-1.3978)] [x2] = [-0.5929 -0.4952]
```

Comment: http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/

Comment: or http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21b_fall_04/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html

Comment: You should specify if you want a generic formula or just want to solve the specific problem that you are posting here, please re-elaborate your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Only need to know how to do it on a calculator as this could be an exam questions and we are not allowed to use matlab!

Comment: Which calculator do you have ? On mine, there's a dedicated function for this matter.

Comment: I have casio fx 570es